# Is there a way to speed up Record Linkage in Python for comparing similar records

Tags: python, record-linkage

I am using the recordlinkage library in Python to detect duplicates in several datasets of estate properties that are web scraped weekly from a couple of websites. For the process I use the following numeric variables as block index: area, rooms, bathrooms and garages and these categorical variables: stratum (6 categories) and type (2 categories). For comparing I use the geographical coordinates, the price and the description using the lcs method; the description is a string that may be up to 1000 characters on some records, but normally it contains 300-500 characters. The issue is that it takes a really long time to compute the comparison, even with 8 jobs (I have tried with less cores and it takes even longer). For example, in one dataset I have 60000 records and when comparing it with itself, it will take roughly 10 hours to compute 20000 possible duplicates, but it shouldn't take that long, right? Is there a way to tweak the process to make it faster?

Here is the code I have been using:

```
## df_in is a pandas DataFrame with all the required columns

block_vars = ['area', 'rooms', 'bathrooms', 'garages', 'stratum', 'type']
compare_vars = [
            String('description', 'description', method='lcs',
                   label='description', threshold=0.95),
            Numeric('originPrice', 'originPrice', method='gauss',
                    label='originPrice', offset=0.2, scale=0.2),
            Geographic('latitude', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'longitude',
                       method='gauss', offset=0.2, label='location')
            ]
indexer = rl.index.Block(block_vars)
candidate_links = indexer.index(df_in)
njobs = 8

## This is the part that takes hours
comparer = rl.Compare(compare_vars, n_jobs=njobs)
compare_vectors = comparer.compute(pairs=candidate_links, x=df_in)

## Model training doesn't take too long
ecm = rl.ECMClassifier(binarize=0.5)
ecm.fit(compare_vectors)
pairs_ecm = ecm.predict(compare_vectors)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with the `String` comparison methods and found out that some of them were not imported from `jellyfish`, so they are not optimized. One of them was the `lcs` method which, for one dataset, could take a whole weekend to run as stated in the question. I changed it to `damerau_levenshtein` and it now takes less than two minutes.

Hope this helps someone in the future :D